# Conditions for if statement using cin not satisfied, body of statement executes anyway

Tags: c++, iostream, conditional-statements

```
if (cin >> var){
    //code 1
}
else{
    //code 2
}
```

This is an example of my code. `var` is of type int, so I don't want code 1 to execute when the user inputs non-int values. If I enter a letter or a symbol, code 1 will not execute and code 2 will execute.  The problem is when the user enters a double value (for example, 3.5) both code 1 and code 2 will execute, but I only want code 2 to execute. Code 1 executes using the truncated value for `var` (for example, if the user enters 3.5, code 1 executes as if the user entered 3) I do use `std::cin.clear()` and `std::cin.ignore()` in code 2, but it doesn't make a difference. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you give us an [example](http://ideone.com) in which both branches are executed?

Comment: you can read a double and convert it to int (double always has space for an exact int) if var == floor(var)

Comment: I'm guessing that the `if` is inside a loop; with `3.5` it reads `3` the first time and executes the first branch, and the next iteration it hits the `.5`, fails to read anything, and executes the second branch.

Comment: I second T.C.s guess. Demo: http://ideone.com/gikyFq

Comment: @BeyelerStudios This was a perfect solution